# Execute multiple python scripts using docker

Tags: python, docker

I want to execute multiple python scripts on Docker in same time.

But I've found something strange in output order.

Below is my test python script.

```
import random
import time


print("start test")

# sleep time
rn = random.randint(30, 45)

# file number
rn_fn = random.randint(0, 10000000)

print("sleep %s seconds ..." % rn)
time.sleep(rn)

print("write file python_test%s_%s ..." % (rn_fn, rn))

txt_file = open('/app/python_test%s_%s.txt' % (rn_fn, rn), 'w')
txt_file.write('test %s!' % rn_fn)
txt_file.close()

print("end write file")
```

When I run my python script twice on the CentOS7 with

```
python test.py &
python test.py &
```

The output is

```
00:00 - start test(1)
00:00 - start test(2)
00:00 - sleep 35 seconds ...(1)
00:00 - sleep 40 seconds ...(2)
00:35 - write file ~.txt(1)
00:35 - end write file(1)
00:40 - write file ~.txt(2)
00:40 - end write file(2)
```

But when I execute it on the docker with

```
docker exec -i container_name /app/test.py &
docker exec -i container_name /app/test.py &
```

The output is

```
00:00 - start test(1)
00:00 - sleep 35 seconds ...(1)
00:35 - write file ~.txt(1)
00:35 - end write file(1)
00:00 - start test(2)
00:00 - sleep 40 seconds ...(2)
00:40 - write file ~.txt(2)
00:40 - end write file(2)
```

Why the print() order is different in centOS and docker?

Does docker prints when its process ends?

Comment: Have you tried `docker exec -i container_name bash -c '/app/test.py & /app/test.py &'`?

Comment: I've tried it, but the output was same. I think tty(-t) option affect output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the Python script from a Docker container, it does not have a tty by default, you have to add `--tty` , `-t` when you are about to run your container,

`docker run -t yourimage`

You could force Python to flush, if you do not want the container to do so, by adding the flush parameter in your print method.

`print("Begin", flush=True)`

Comment: I didn't know that print method have that parameter. Thank you for your answer.